# HP Blade System Won't Come Up

Tags: hp, blade-server

I recently [asked a question on here regarding our HP Onboard Administrator not responding in a C7000 Blade Enclosure](https://serverfault.com/questions/742195/hp-blade-system-7000-fans-about-to-take-off/742214#742214).  I was advised it was faulty and after contacting our 3rd line support company was sent a replacement and advised I would need to reboot the entire enclosure.

I've done that this morning and now it won't come back up!  All the NICs on the back aren't showing any activity at all and when I attempt to power up the blades the 'NIC 1' light flashed red.  Does anyone have any idea?  Really concerned now as I can't get in touch with the 3rd line organisation and my faith in them has really taken a hammering.

Any one have any idea why this is happening?  The OBA light is also still inactive so looks like the reboot didn't even fix that.

Answer (score 1):

The answer here is the same one I provided before at:
[HP Blade System 7000 - Fans About to Take Off](https://serverfault.com/questions/742195/hp-blade-system-7000-fans-about-to-take-off/742214#742214)

Call HP and have them send an authorized technician to your site to diagnose and fix the problem. Even if you're out of support, they will do it for a price.

There's no use in trying to guess ho to fix this at this point.